# java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 08/13/2015

Tags: android, web-services, soap

I am so sorry if this question is stupid. But i stuck in this error about 2 days. It makes me crazy. This is my problem

```
11-14 14:28:43.937  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot serialize: 08/13/2015
11-14 14:28:43.937  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:708)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeProperty(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:692)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:661)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeObjectBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:645)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeElement(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:702)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.writeBody(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:618)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.write(SoapEnvelope.java:198)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.createRequestData(Transport.java:111)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:119)
11-14 14:28:43.947  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:95)
11-14 14:28:43.957  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at com.example.vuong.final_project_pott.view.SearchTicketActivity$JSonAsyncTask.doInBackground(SearchTicketActivity.java:283)
11-14 14:28:43.957  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at com.example.vuong.final_project_pott.view.SearchTicketActivity$JSonAsyncTask.doInBackground(SearchTicketActivity.java:242)
11-14 14:28:43.957  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
11-14 14:28:43.957  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
11-14 14:28:43.957  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
11-14 14:28:43.957  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
11-14 14:28:43.967  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
11-14 14:28:43.967  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-14 14:28:43.967  14479-14605/com.example.vuong.final_project_pott D/Error﹕ Cannot serialize: 08/13/2015
```

This problem come when I tried calling webmethod of webservices(is built by .NET).  I was looking for in google and starkoverflow, and try same solution as implement KmvSerialize, using MarshalDate class but not working for me.Here is webmethod

```
[WebMethod]
    public String searchingTickets(String date, String departure, String arrival)
    {
        List<Ticket_Information> listTicket = new List<Ticket_Information>();
        String status;
        DateTime datetime = new DateTime();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("workstation id=OrderingTicketsTS.mssql.somee.com;packet size=4096;user id=b5prolh_SQLLogin_1;pwd=dxtcq1cbar;data source=OrderingTicketsTS.mssql.somee.com;persist security info=False;initial catalog=OrderingTicketsTS");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from ticket_information where Date = '" + date + "' and Departure = '" + departure + "' and arrival = '" +arrival+ "'", conn);
            conn.Open();

            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    Ticket_Information ticket_information = new Ticket_Information();
                    if (dr.GetBoolean(9) == true)
                    {
                        status = "Sold Out";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        status = "Still";
                    }
                    ticket_information.ID_Ticket = dr.GetString(0);
                    ticket_information.Company = dr.GetString(1);
                    ticket_information.Departure = dr.GetString(2);
                    ticket_information.Arrival = dr.GetString(3);
                    ticket_information.Vehicles_type = dr.GetString(4);
                    ticket_information.Services = dr.GetString(5);
                    datetime = dr.GetDateTime(6);
                    ticket_information.Date = datetime.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
                    ticket_information.Time = dr.GetString(7);
                    ticket_information.Price = dr.GetDouble(8);
                    ticket_information.Ticket_Status = status;
                    listTicket.Add(ticket_information);
                }  
            }    
            return listTicket.ParserJSon();
            conn.Close();
    }
```

Type of date parameter in SQL server is Date. When I run webservices on local and test, It works perfect. After that, I called this method in android by Ksoap2 and my problem appears. 
Here is my SearchTicketActivity:

```
public class SearchTicketActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener, Serializable {
    private EditText departure;
    private EditText arrival;
    private EditText date;
    private ListView listView;
    private TextView tvtest;
    private ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    private ArrayList<TicketInforModel> ticketInforModelArrayList = new ArrayList<TicketInforModel>();
    private TicketInforModel ticketInforModel;
    private ArrayAdapter<TicketInforModel> arrAdapterTicket;
    private DatePickerDialog fromDatePickerDialog;
    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter;


   private final String TAG_IDTICKET = "ID_Ticket";
    private final String TAG_Company = "Company";
    private final String TAG_Departure = "Departure";
    private final String TAG_Arrival = "Arrival";
    private final String TAG_VEHICLESTYPE = "Vehicles_type";
    private final String TAG_SERVICES = "Services";
    private final String TAG_Date = "Date";
    private final String TAG_Time = "Time";
    private final String TAG_Price = "Price";
    private final String TAG_TicketStatus = "Ticket_Status";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.searchticket_main);

        departure = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_departure);
        arrival = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_arrival);
        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_date);
        listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lv_ticket);
        tvtest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_test);

        dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US);

        setDateTimeField();
        Button btn_searching = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_searching);
        btn_searching.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JSonAsyncTask jSonAsyncTask = new JSonAsyncTask();
                jSonAsyncTask.execute();
                if(ticketInforModelArrayList.size() >0 ){
                    tvtest.setText("done");
                }else{
                    tvtest.setText("Error");
                }


            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == date) {
            fromDatePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }

    public class JSonAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void,Void> implements Serializable {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            final String TAG_SOAPACTION1 = "http://tempuri.org/searchingTickets";
            final String TAG_NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            final String TAG_METHODNAME = "searchingTickets";
            final String TAG_URL = "http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx";


            SoapObject request=new SoapObject(TAG_NAMESPACE, TAG_METHODNAME);


            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.name = "date";
            pi.setValue(date.getText());
            pi.type = String.class;
            request.addProperty(pi);

            pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.name = "departure";
            pi.setValue(departure.getText());
            pi.type = String.class;
            request.addProperty(pi);

            pi.name = "arrival";
            pi.setValue(arrival.getText());
            pi.type = String.class;
            request.addProperty(pi);

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope=new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet=true;

            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE transport=new HttpTransportSE(TAG_URL);
            transport.debug = true;

            try{
                transport.call(TAG_SOAPACTION1,envelope);
                SoapPrimitive data = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();

                String jsonText=data.toString();
                JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(jsonText);

                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                    ticketInforModel = new TicketInforModel();
                    JSONObject jsonObject =(JSONObject)jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    ticketInforModel.set_IdTicket(jsonObject.getString(TAG_IDTICKET).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_company(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Company).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_departure(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Departure).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_arrival(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Arrival).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_vehicletype(jsonObject.getString(TAG_VEHICLESTYPE).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_services(jsonObject.getString(TAG_SERVICES).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_date(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Date).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_time(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Time).toString());
                    ticketInforModel.set_price(Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString(TAG_Price).toString()));
                    ticketInforModel.set_ticket_Status(jsonObject.getString(TAG_TicketStatus).toString());
                    ticketInforModelArrayList.add(ticketInforModel);
                }

            }catch (JSONException e){
                Log.d("JSON",e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Loi gi day",e.getMessage());
            } catch (SoapFault soapFault) {
                soapFault.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Soap",soapFault.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("Error", ex.getMessage());
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        }
    }

    private void setDateTimeField() {
        try{
            date.setOnClickListener(this);
            final Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            fromDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    Calendar newDate = Calendar.getInstance();;
                    newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth-1);
                    if(newDate.getTime().getTime() > (newCalendar.getTime().getTime())){
                        final AlertDialog builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchTicketActivity.this).setTitle("Notification").setMessage("This is a date of future! We will get current date for this review!").show();

                        //this code below is coppied in https://xjaphx.wordpress.com/2011/07/13/auto-close-dialog-after-a-specific-time/
                        final Timer t = new Timer();
                        t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                            public void run() {
                                builder.dismiss(); // when the task active then close the dialog
                                t.cancel(); // also just top the timer thread, otherwise, you may receive a crash report
                            }
                        }, 2000); // after 2 second (or 2000 miliseconds), the task will be active.
                        date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newCalendar.getTime()));

                    }

                    else{
                        newDate.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                        date.setText(dateFormatter.format(newDate.getTime()));
                    }
                }
            },newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            showMessages("Something Wrong!");
        }
    }

    private void showMessages(String messages) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle("Notification").setMessage(messages).setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            }
        }).show();
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Here is TicketInforModel:

```
public class TicketInforModel implements Serializable {

    //Data Ticket
    private String _IdTicket;
    private String _company;
    private String _departure;
    private String _arrival;
    private String _vehicletype;
    private String _services;
    private String _date;
    private String _time ;
    private double _price;
    private String _ticket_Status ;

    public TicketInforModel(String IDticket,String Company, String Departure, String Arrival, String Vehicletype, String Services, String Date, String Time, double Price, String Ticket_status){
        this.set_IdTicket(IDticket);
        this.set_company(Company);
        this.set_departure(Departure);
        this.set_arrival(Arrival);
        this.set_vehicletype(Vehicletype);
        this.set_services(Services);
        this.set_date(Date);
        this.set_time(Time);
        this.set_price(Price);
        this.set_ticket_Status(Ticket_status);
    }
    public TicketInforModel(){

    }


    public String get_company() {
        return _company;
    }

    public void set_company(String _company) {
        this._company = _company;
    }

    public String get_departure() {
        return _departure;
    }

    public void set_departure(String _departure) {
        this._departure = _departure;
    }

    public String get_arrival() {
        return _arrival;
    }

    public void set_arrival(String _arrival) {
        this._arrival = _arrival;
    }

    public String get_vehicletype() {
        return _vehicletype;
    }

    public void set_vehicletype(String _vehicletype) {
        this._vehicletype = _vehicletype;
    }

    public String get_services() {
        return _services;
    }

    public void set_services(String _services) {
        this._services = _services;
    }

    public String get_date() {
        return _date;
    }

    public void set_date(String _date) {
        this._date = _date;
    }

    public String get_time() {
        return _time;
    }

    public void set_time(String _time) {
        this._time = _time;
    }

    public double get_price() {
        return _price;
    }

    public void set_price(double _price) {
        this._price = _price;
    }

    public String get_ticket_Status() {
        return _ticket_Status;
    }

    public void set_ticket_Status(String _ticket_Status) {
        this._ticket_Status = _ticket_Status;
    }

    public String get_IdTicket() {
        return _IdTicket;
    }

    public void set_IdTicket(String _IdTicket) {
        this._IdTicket = _IdTicket;
    }

}
```

You can view my webservices in [here](http://vuongphgc60287.somee.com/mywebservices.asmx)

Please help me if you can and thanks for reading my question.